Overlay service without run forceground
My application using OverlayService to display view over home sreen using startForceground service.
But from Android OS 14, Google request all application have to meet "foreground service types".
It is disappointing because my application is not in any of them.
Besides using the service to draw an overlay view, are there any other ways?
Or how did you handle this situation if the application did not meet Google's requirements?
Thank you ~
